# Equal volume when doing birkat kohanim with a microphone

Tags: halacha, technology, speech-talking, birchas-kohanim, loud-quiet

I attended a musical davening this week, and to accommodate the large crowd, the chazzan wore a microphone. The kohanim however did not. The result of this was that the chazzan's voice ended up much louder than the kohanim's.

I know that there is a halacha that neither the chazzan nor the kohanim should raise their voice louder than the other.

How does this halacha play out when one is artificially much louder than the other? Should the chazzan whisper into the mic to try and equalize the volume? Or perhaps it's fine if they both speak normally, and it doesn't matter what happens to the sound once it leaves their mouths?

Comment: Can you edit in a citation for the halacha you mention in your second paragraph?

Comment: I seem vaguely to recall that that's the practice at the Wall on the day the heavily-populated _b'racha_ is done.